# How to get message body from RoutingContext?

Tags: java, vert.x

I created a vert.x HTTP server and I want to receive messages from clients in json format.
This is my code:

```
public class HttpServerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> future) {
        Router router = Router.router(vertx)
            .exceptionHandler(ex -> log.error("Error: " + ex));
        router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
        router.route("/getData").handler(this::getRequestHandler);

        HttpServerOptions serverOptions = new HttpServerOptions();
        vertx.createHttpServer(serverOptions)
                .requestHandler(router::accept)
                .listen(9539, result -> {
                    if (result.succeeded()) {
                        future.complete();
                    } else {
                        future.fail(result.cause());
                    }
                });
    }

    private void getRequestHandler(RoutingContext request) {
        JsonObject data = request.getBodyAsJson();  // In this place I had exception
        ...
        request.response().end("{\"reply\":\"ok\"}");
    }
}
```

When my handler was fire and I get some message from the client I get this exception:

```
io.vertx.core.json.DecodeException: Failed to decode:Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (String)"{"ClientRequest":["ok"],"Type":"Test"[truncated 678 chars]; line: 1, column: 1])
```

How can I avoid this exception and all time get the full message?

Comment: String data = request.getBodyAsString()  instead and check the request is valid json

Comment: @David It doesn't solve my issue because of all clients sent to the server valid json and I want to get it all. In my case in 90% of client messages was truncated by vert.x I couldn't lose these messages.

Comment: I mean in debug mode stop at that line and extract the string and validate the json

Comment: @David Yes I did that and when json is too large it was not valid (but clients sent valid json) if the client sent a small json is ok.

Comment: try setBodyLimit(-1) on your body handler?

Comment: @David I set -1 for the method setBodyLimit(-1), but it's not working for me. Maybe when client send me to request his buffer have to limit?

Comment: @david there's no body limit by default.

Comment: @oleg can you check with wireshark that the payload is fully sent by the client and the content length header is correct? Otherwise please report a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the HTTP method

```
router.route("/getData").handler(this::getRequestHandler);
```

is expecting an HTTP GET, but what you need is an HTTP POST:

```
router.post("/getData")
  .consumes("application/json")
  .handler(this::getRequestHandler);
```

will accept json in the body. The consumes is optional and enforces the client to only send json.

I would also suggest to name the route "/data" instead of "/getData" to conform with the concept of RESTful APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible the client is not sending a valid json.
This is a valid exception to handle in that case.
For logging the request, you can simply use request.getBodyAsString() before doing getBodyAsJson()